# Como fazer o tratamento dos erros no Mongoose de maneira otimizada

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, express.js

Estou começando a trabalhar com o MongoDB + Mongoose e estou tendo problemas para tratar os erros que o mongoose gera. Um dos mesmo é quando há uma chave duplicada para um parâmetro que deveria ser único. Ex:

**Model (UsuarioModel)**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const UsuarioSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email: {type: String,required: true,index: true},
    senha: {type: String,required: true},
    nome: { type: String, required: true}
});
const UsuarioModel = mongoose.model('Usuario', UsuarioSchema, 'Usuario');    

module.exports = UsuarioModel;
```

Usando esse model, o mongoose não poderá salvar novos documentos que tenham o e-mail repetido. Isso já consegui entender, fazer funcionar e ver a resposta dentro da minha aplicação. Ex:

**Código que salva o usuário na rota(POST) do ExpressJS**

```
UsuarioRoute.post('/', (req, res) => {
    let Usuario = new UsuarioModel(req.body);
    Usuario.save((err, Usuario) => {
        err ? res.status(400).send(err) : res.send('ok.');
    });
});
```

Meu problema é que, quando ocorre um erro (como por exemplo a tentativa de salvamento onde o e-mail já existe, o Mongoose não me traz isso de uma forma amigável. A mensagem que recebi na variável `err` do código acima foi essa:

```
{
    "code":11000,
    "index":0,
    "errmsg":"E11000 duplicate key error collection: foo.Usuario index: email_1 dup key: { : \"a@a.com\" }",
    "op":{
        "email":"a@a.com",
        "nome":"foo",
        "senha":"123",
    }
}
```

Existe alguma forma mais "amigável" de eu entender esse erro? a única maneira que eu pensei foi de fazer um tratamento específico com base no parâmetro `code` do JSON que o Mongoose me retornou mas assim eu teria que fazer uma micro-biblioteca só de tratamento de erros... Realmente é a única forma de tratar isso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A melhor opção para esse tipo de situação é fazer uma consulta antes se aquele  e-mail está em uso. Isso porque na maioria dos casos têm-se um cluster com diversos nodos do mongodb e a leitura (`read`) é muito menos custosa do que a escrita (`write`). Ex:

```js
UsuarioRoute.post('/', async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const exists = await UsuarioModel.count({ email: req.body.email })
      if(exists) {
        return res
          .status(400)
          .send(`o email "${req.body.email}" já está em uso`)
      }
      await new UsuarioModel(req.body).save();
      res.send('ok.');
    } catch(e) {
      res.status(400).send(err)
    }
});
```

Answer (score -2):

Acredito que seja por não adicionar o parâmetro `unique` como true, e por boa pratica mude o nome da collection para "usuarios"

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const UsuarioSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email: {type: String,required: true,index: true, unique: true},
    senha: {type: String,required: true},
    nome: { type: String, required: true}
});
const UsuarioModel = mongoose.model('Usuario', UsuarioSchema, 'usuarios');    

module.exports = UsuarioModel;
```

Para saber mais entre nesse link:  [unique indexes](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/index-unique/#unique-index-and-missing-field)

Comment: não existe nenhuma documentação para a "boa prática" de nomenclatura com plural, é apenas uma convenção de um grupo de desenvolvedores. Eu já acredito que a coleção deve ter o nome da entidade, se a entidade é no singular então o nome será no singular.